Domain of a Graph That is Just a Horizontal Line with Points at the Beginning and the End.
I have a graph that is just a horizontal line with one full painted point at the beginning of the graph $x=0$ and one empty point at the end $x=10$.
Would the correct answer for domain of this function be [$0, 10$)?
I'm not sure what these points mean, but I assume full point means that it is included and empty point means that it is excluded?

Yes, that is the usual convention.

Yes, your assumption is correct. The "full-painted point" you refer to is typically called a closed dot, with the empty one being called an open dot.
As you inferred, the closed dot indicates that the endpoint is part of the solution. An open dot indicates that the endpoint of the ray is not part of the solution.
